# robocopy /MIR recover deleted files from the destination

Tags: windows, windows-10, data-recovery, robocopy, file-recovery

While trying to move my `c:\users` to `d:\users` (By using a Junction)
I was very careless, and used `robocopy c:\users d:\users /MIR /MOVE`
it moved some, but then halted on a symlinks...
so I added `robocopy c:\users d:\users /MIR /MOVE /sj /sl` to the mix and well (forgetting the now deleted source folders)
as you can imagine, it found many folders that doesn't exists in source, therefore deleted them from the destination too.

Now:

1. I am pissed at myself for being so hasty using /MOVE, but hey, stupidity happen!
2. is there a reasonable way to recover my lost ~30GB of files?
3. Even if I can recover the files, will Windows servive? or I am doomed to a fresh installation?

Comment: For whom it may concern, new installation is undergo :) PC is misbehaving!